# Excessive frequency deviation for DMR handsets?

Tags: software-defined-radio, dmr

A Hytera DMR handset that I am working with has a frequency deviation of 2300-2700 Hz. This is higher than the expected 1944.0 Hz frequency deviation specified in the DMR specification (ETSI TS 102 361-1). Is it expected that low cost handsets have excessive frequency deviation? I'm wondering how the receiver performs synchronization when the frequency deviation can be so far out of range?

[image]

More info:

- I/Q samples are collected with an SDR
- This question is *not* about carrier frequency offset but rather the FSK frequency deviation
- To determine the deviation, I used an FM demodulator then measured the distance between minimum and maximum deviation.

**Update 1:**

- the frequency deviation is closer to 2100-2400 Hz after further measurement.

Comment: how do you derive the frequency deviation from your recording, *exactly*?

Comment: FM demod oversampled data, then measure the max to min outer deviation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verification through simulation of a DMR burst shows that the excessive frequency deviation is caused by the overshoot from the pulse shape filter ($\alpha$=0.20). The DMR modulator uses a RRC at the transmitter and receiver which can cause the deviation to go beyond 1944 Hz.

[image: DMR Modulator block diagram]

Here are the ideal simulated frequency deviations after the RRC filter:

[image: Frequency deviations after RRC filter]

Answer (score 1):

> Is it expected that low cost handsets have excessive frequency deviation?

No. Such a transmitter wouldn't work with standards-compliant receivers. Most symbol decisions would end up being wrong, assuming sensible decisions regions.

The "zero hypothesis" here is that your transmitter works compliant to the standard, and your measurement methodology is off.  (Sad, but true!)

> To determine the deviation, I used an FM demodulator then measured the distance between minimum and maximum deviation.

That's sadly not a proper way to do that!

Remember that in actual FM transmissions, the audio message is integrated before it because the frequency deviation; so an FM demod will give you the *derivative* of the instantaneous frequency. Now, the derivative of the instantaneous frequency (for the purely theoretical "perfect" FM demodulator) is given by the symbol rate together with the differences in frequency, not just by the frequencies.

Even if you have a demodulator that leaves out the derivative (that in the end just being a bit of a highpass to the audio), the relationship between instantaneous frequency and output of the demodulator is a proportional one, but you have a degree of freedom in designing your demodulator's frequency sensitivity. So, you  need to check that very closely what you're doing here.

Comment: The software based FM demod I am using takes into account the sample rate: `fm = np.angle(x[1:] * np.conj(x[:-1]))*fs/ (2*np.pi)`, where `x` is the oversampled complex baseband FSK signal and `fs` is the sample rate (integer multiple of symbol rate). This does give the proper frequency deviation. I have used this technique for many FSK signals.

Comment: that's not an FM demod, but a frequency demodulator (I know, this is very nitpicky, sorry, but when I hear "FM", that's referring to a specific method of modulation for analog signals); but, hm! do you do that during the say center 10% of the symbol period, or over the full signal? I ask because of the overshoot you might get through pulse shaping prior to FSK on the transmit side.

Comment: The estimation if performed over the full signal

Comment: huh! So, sanity checks are in order: do we have an easy way to check whether the symbol rate is as it should be? (if in doubt, approximate the discrete derivative of your `fm`, look for the zero crossings, that's where the derivative of the signal is zero, and that should be at the symbol instants)

Comment: That's a clever way to resolve symbol timing! How does that work if there are multiple symbols of the same value in a row? You won't have a 0 crossing.

Comment: that's right! The trick with these thigs is typically this: only in 1 of 4 cases, the next symbol is the same as the last. In 1 of 4 cases, the next symbol is the perfect opposite of the current symbol, and you get a "clean" maximum in your pulse-shaped waveform. In half of the cases, it's in between. So, you look for the distance of points where zero crossings occur that is somewhat close to a multiple of the symbol rate you expect. You can, by the way, also do a similar thing to the waveform without taking the derivative: look for zero crossings. They *only* happen when the sign of the

Comment: symbol changes, and when they happen it's "somewhere close to the middle between two symbol instants", and if you then group them and do an average (for example by means of a slow control loop), you converge against the "true middle-between-symbols distance".

Comment: @BigBrownBear00 I can't find a "nicer" explanation right now, but go and read https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php?title=Polyphase_Clock_Sync maybe. The idea is this: you take the derivative of the receive signal after convolution with the matched filter (MF). That MF'ed signal should, in many to most cases, have a local maximum at the precise sample instant. We define "derivative of the signal" by saying "hey, derivation is a linear operation, and so is MFing, so we simply combine them, change order, so that we convolve with the derivative of the MF". That has the advantage that you can get

Comment: a very low-noise error estimate but looking at the output of the derivative matched filter (DMF) at where you *think* so far sample instants are. If you then weigh that with the amplitude of the MF output at the same points, you get like "reliability-weighted timing errors", which is neat, because you can use them in a timing control loop to make them as small as possible. Now, our problem is a *tad* different:

Comment: We don't know the repetition rates of the points where the error should be minimal – the symbol rate – yet, so we cannot just evaluate the output of this timing error detector at the presumable symbol instants. Instead, if gives us a signal with periodic dips that aren't as dependent on the data symbols. So, trying to find an initial guess can involve taking the DFT of that signal (or, 1/that signal), and using that rough idea of periodicity to initialize the loop, then you can get "smart" and say things like "we always are a little late, no matter how much we correct, so the symbol period we…

Comment: … assume must be a bit too long"; and from there you can adjust things in higher-order loops. ()if that is necessary at all – if you're always a small bit late, it might not be that bad, because your eye diagram will still be widely open at that point).